# Android Expansion File. How can I put library in expansion file

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I am working on an app where we are using lots of libraries to provide funtionalities like reading PDF,docx,ppt etc also we have a youtube player and many more other libraries.

Due to the design of our app, we are using lots of resources to design UI(resources is about 22 mb). We are using these images in layouts (which are lot if you ask).

I checked to see whether we can go down on using Background images, but more we strip them, our client asks for more features to integrate in the app which again increases the size to more then 50 MB (Google play limitation as mentioned here [Google play expansion file setup link](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)) .

I am looking for a solution where I can somehow remove the libraries while compiling the app to keep size under limit of 50 MB and put it in expansion file (I know this seems to be a problem, cuz I don't know how I will compile the app without those libraries) and load it on run time .

I am very confused here, Can some one help me here ??

Comment: I guess you can only put **resource files** in an expansion file, **not libraries**. Which makes sense to me, since resources can be enormous, while libraries should be small portions of shared code -    http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: @Der Golem  Thank you for answering, but as i said we are using lots of resources (background images) to follow the design and we are using these images from the layout xml. If i strip those images, I'll have to use them from JAVA and not xml rite ? Aren't there any way to work with the libraries we are using ? cuz my client is always asking for new funtionality to implement.. which will end up adding more JAR SDKs..

Comment: Customers must be educated (trained) not to ask the moon. If something is not reasonable, they must be convinced to accept something less. A sort of compromise. Obviously, you want to make them happy, by optimizing the resources (i.e. using **vectorial graphics** instead of pictorial, reducing your code to the bones and **avoiding redundancies**, ...). But when it's too much, it goes beyond **reasonable requirements**. Audio and video files are perfect candidates for expansion files, as well as large databases.